# customizing each button in kendo grid

Tags: button, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with custom buttons at the end of the row. This is done in the following way:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content" style="float: right">
                <button id="textButton" style="margin: 5px;">Open WFR</button>
                <button id="textButton_remind" style="margin-left: 5px;">Remind Me</button>
            </div>

 columns: [
        {
            field: "WFR", title: "WFR", filterable: {
                cell: {
                    operator: "contains",
                    suggestionOperator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "Activity", title: "Activity" },
        { field: "Date", title: "Date" },
        { field: "Group", title: "Group" },
        { field: "MoreInfo", title: "More Information", hidden: true },
        { field: "Read", title: "Read", hidden: true },
        { template: '<button id="textButton" style="margin: 5px;">Open WFR</button>', title: 'View Event'}

 $("#textButton").kendoButton();
```

The problem I am having is that, it is only changing the first button in the grid. so if I have 3 rows, only the first button is changing. When I create different IDs and implement them as a kendo button then it works. How can I dynamically assign an id to the `<button id="textButton"` to create individual buttons (`$("#textButton").kendoButton();`)

[image: Example of what is currently happening]

Comment: Can you please let me know if my answer solves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

use a class instead of id

```
 { template: '<button class="textButton" style="margin: 5px;">Open WFR</button>', title: 'View Event'}
```

and do this instead

```
$(".textButton").kendoButton();
```

I suggest you use the dataBound event of your grid to convert them to buttons

```
$(..).kendoGrid({
   dataBound: function(e) {
       $('.textButton').kendoButton();
   }
});
```

I do suggest this approach instead cleaner less taking effect on the whole DOM.

here is the dojo and the code https://dojo.telerik.com/EhUNUwOr

```
<div id="my-grid"></div>
<script>
    $('#my-grid').kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'firstName',
                title: 'First Name'
            },
            {
                template: '<button class="grid-text-button">A</button><button class="grid-text-button">B</button>',
                title: 'Actions'
            }
        ],
        dataSource: [
            {
                id: 1,
                firstName: 'David'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                firstName: 'Chuck'
            }
        ],
        dataBound: function(e) {
            var $rows = e.sender.items();
            $rows.find('.grid-text-button').kendoButton();
        }
    });
</script>
```